# New question doesn't show up in the tag's "Newest" list

Tags: bug, question-lists

Consider the Q

[Autosizing a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947100/autosizing-a-checkbox)

It was created an hour ago, at 2023-04-06 07:56:01Z, but still it doesn't show up in the Delphi tag's list of newest questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi?tab=Newest

However, it *does* show up in the list of active questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi?tab=Active

I have never seen this behaviour before. Is it a Stack Overflow bug?

Comment: I observe the same within a newest list for questions tagged [tag:c++]. It started to behave like this about 2hrs ago.

Comment: Checking [popular tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) seems to agree with @πάνταῥεῖ's observation that most of them are stuck since a few hours ago ([tag:android] was "only" 1 hour ago).

Comment: Seems to work again just now.

Comment: ... and looks like the cache has just been mass-updated... (now correctly showing)

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the Delphi tag is also working correctly now.